# How to get container height after I loaded the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using a `load` method, i am loading a content to existing div. while the content is lengthen, i would like to increase the existing div's height to match the loading content.

how can i find the loaded content height, in case if that wrapped on a div called `pageContent`

any help?

```
var container = $('existingDiv')
this.container.load("Doc/chapter1/index.html", function(element){
                console.log($(element).innerHeight())//getting 0
container.height(element.height())//?
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can do that with simple CSS (of course - that depends on your div complexity - sometimes you need JS):
You can use `min-height`, `max-height` and `overflow` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it help to just use css?

```
#existingDiv {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 250px;
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I am not sure how your `css` framework looks like, but this could work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#existingDiv {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: <any-value>;
    max-height: <any-value>;
}
```

Try this. This is supposed to give the container automatic height. But again it depends upon all the other css you are applying on the parent containers and the elements surrounding to this container